# How to pass multiple VPC CIDRs to security_group_rule resource in terraform V.15

Tags: terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform0.12+

I need to pass the list of VPC CIDR ranges to an **aws_security_group_rule** resource.

I'm using terraform version: v.15.0

Here is the code I'm using:

```
variable "list_of_vps" {
  description = "CIDR covering kops compute nodes"
  type        = list
  default     = ["vpc-foo", "vpc-bar"]
}

data "aws_vpcs" "list_of_vpcs"{
  count = length(var.list_of_vps)
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["vpc-${element(var.list_of_vps, count.index)}"]
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "get_vpc_id" {
    count = length(data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs.ids)
    id    = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs.ids)[count.index]
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs.ids)
  type              = "ingress"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  from_port         = 5432
  to_port           = 5432
  cidr_blocks       = [data.aws_vpc.get_vpc_id[count.index].cidr_block]
  security_group_id = module.postgress.postgress_security_group_id
}
```

I am m getting this below error.

```
on data.tf line 10, in data "aws_vpc" "get_vpc_id":
  10:     count = length(data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs.ids)
  Because data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed 
 on specific instances.
 For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs[count.index]
    Error: Missing resource instance key
 
   on data.tf line 15, in data "aws_vpc" "get_vpc_id":
   15:   id = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.get_vpc_id.ids)[count.index]
 
 Because data.aws_vpcs.prod has a "count" set, its attributes must be accessed
 on specific instances.
 For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
     data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs[count.index]
```

Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform seems to be returning this error because of your expression `data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs.ids`. That expression isn't valid, because `data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs` is a list of objects rather than a single object, and so you'd need to tell Terraform which element of the list you want to access the `.id` attribute from.

However, I imagine your goal here was instead to get the number of elements in the list, in which case you can get there by asking Terraform for the length of the list of objects itself, rather than of a hypothetical attribute of that list:

```
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs)
```

For your other error in the expression with the `tolist` call, I'm a little less sure what your intention was. It seems like your module is taking a set of names of single VPCs and your goal that for each one of those you want to find the corresponding VPC with that name and determine its CIDR block. Since you only expect to find one VPC per name in that list I don't think you need the `data.aws_vpcs.list_of_vpcs` at all: that is for finding *multiple* VPCs matching particular criteria. Instead, you can filter by the Name tag directly in the singlular `data.aws_vpc` data source. Perhaps like this:

```
variable "vpc_names" {
  type = set(string)
}

data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
  for_each = var.vpc_names

  tags = {
    Name = each.value
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {
  for_each = data.aws_vpc.selected

  type              = "ingress"
  protocol          = "tcp"
  from_port         = 5432
  to_port           = 5432
  cidr_blocks       = [each.value.cidr_block]
  security_group_id = module.postgress.postgress_security_group_id
}
```

The above tells Terraform to look up one VPC per element of `var.vpc_names`, expecting to find exactly one VPC with the given name (it'll fail if there isn't exactly one). It then declares a security group rule for each of those VPCs, where `each.value.cidr_block` means to use the `cidr_block` attribute from the current element of `aws_vpc.selected`.